# Print numbers on a OpenCV image

Tags: c++, opencv

i have a vector that describes all the features in an Mat image in OpenCV.
I want to print all the points with their respective numbers that are nothing more than the indices of the vector.

What i want it's an image like this:

[image]

what is the easiest way?
I have to use the cv::putText?

Comment: You need a way to convert an int to string (e.g. stringstreams) and a way to render a string to an openCV image (e.g. putText). Both findable on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`putText`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext) is what you're looking for. This [OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/random_generator_and_text/random_generator_and_text.html#drawing-2) shows how to use `putText`.